# Using a variable value from one method in different one in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Firstly sorry for asking so many questions here the past couple of weeks, I'm new to android studio and finding it tough to figure out a lot of the core concepts by myself.
In regards to the question, I have a project set up so whatever you type into the "1.2, -1.2" ect parameters you will find you the distance between two places and your answer will be displayed as a toast. However, I want the latitudes and longitueds to be variables.

```
Button button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Double distance = 1.0;
                int val = 1;

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are "     + String.valueOf(distance
                        (1.2, -1.2, 1.3, -2.4, "K")) + "kilometers away     from the flag", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
        });
```

I have the following two methods and I want the values LatLng and currentLatitude and currentLongitude doubles for the parameters above.

```
    private void setUpMap() { 
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(53.3835,6.5996)).title("Marker"));         
}
```

and

```
private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());

        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude,     currentLongitude);

        //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new     LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)).title("Current     Location"));
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("I am here!");
        mMap.addMarker(options);
          mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    }
```

Any insight on how to do it would be much appreciated. From what I've read I know I'll need to split the LatLng variable into strings but thats all I can think of so far

Comment: no need to be sorry, as long as the questions are of good quality, that's what SO is for.

Comment: Out of curiosity would this be considered a question of good quality?

Comment: Are those methods in the same class ?

Comment: @vlatkozelka yes they're all in my mainActivity.

Comment: how much programming experience do you have? java or any other language

Comment: @Adi an average amount of experience in java. I know most of the core concepts and I've written a few programs but I just never understood getting variables from one method and putting them in another and that kind of thing

Comment: then you must know how to pass parameters to methods/functions and returning values.

Comment: although my answer got upvoted and is probably correct, it is not really the only valid answer, as it would be different depending on the situation. I suggest you go learn a bit of C (not c++) and learn how to pass values as parameters or addresses to methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those 2 methods are in the same class then just make those 2 variables attributes of that class, else you will need to pass them to the corresponding classes. I will demonstrate in a simpler example than your code :

```
public class MyClass(){

    private int lat;
    private int longt;

//constructors ,setters and getters

    public void method1(){

//affecting those attributes with values
        lat = 1;
        longt = 2;

    }

    public void method2(){

        //simply access the attributes
        System.out.println("lat "+lat+"  longt  "+longt);

    }


}
```

Reading the comments , I think I need to further explain to you that when a variable is declared inside a method, it is local to that method, and therefor it will be "destroyed" (garbage collected or w.e) when that method is done doing it's job. But when a variable is declared outside a method, like the class's attributes, you can still refer to it whenever you need to, until the instance of that class is "destroyed".

Comment: Nice answer, I would like to add, that `method1()` should always be executed before `method2()` to avoid `NullPointerExceptions` which occur when a `variable` is accessed but has no `value`. Else, one yould check if they are `null` before accessing them.

Comment: Thanks very much that worked and your explanation made it a lot clear to me. Does ordering matter ie should my main method be at the bottom of the class or is it all the same?

Comment: ordering doesn't matter in Java, it matters in C for all I know. But you need to make sure lat and longt aren't null when accessed , so basically call method1 before method2